# Firestore query not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Firestore]

Shown above is my firestore collection.

I am attempting to get data from this collection using a Google Cloud Function that I have deployed:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

module.exports=  function(request, response){ 
     let results = []   
     admin.firestore().collection('news_stories')
     .get()
     .then(docs => docs.map(doc => results.push(doc.data())))
     .catch(e => resoponse.status(400).send(e))

      response.status(200).send(results)
}
```

When I run the above function I get an:

> Error: could not handle the request

I also tried running the function this way to see if it would work.

```
  module.exports=  function(request, response){ 
     let ref = admin.firestore().collection('news_stories')
     .get()
     .then(docs =>   response.status(200).send(docs))
     .catch(e => resoponse.status(400).send(e))
}
```

This function returned a this JSON object:

[image: return object]

There is no information regarding data or any of the docs.

I uploaded the collection to the firestore DB using this function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

module.exports = function(request,response){
   if(!request.body.data){
      response.status(422).send({error: 'missing data'})
   }
   let data = request.body.data
   data.map(item => { 
      admin.firestore().collection('news_stories').add({item})
      })
     response.status(200).send('success!')
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Why is the function not returning any of the documents?

Answer (score 2):

Data is retrieved from Firestore asynchronously. By the time your send you response back to the caller, the results haven't been retrieved from Firestore yet.

It's easiest to see this by replacing the bulk of the code with three log statements:

```
console.log("Before starting get");
admin.firestore().collection('news_stories')
  .get()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("In then()");
  });
console.log("After starting get");
```

*It's best if you run the above in a regular node.js command, instead of in the Cloud Functions environment, since the latter may actually kill the command before the data is loaded.*

The output of the above is:

> Before starting get
>
> After starting get
>
> In then()

That is probably not the order that you expected. But because the data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, the code after the callback function is allowed to continue straight away. Then when the data comes back from Firestore, your callback is invoked and can use the data as it needs to.

The solution is to move all the code that requires the data **into** the `then()` handler:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

module.exports=  function(request, response){ 
     admin.firestore().collection('news_stories')
     .get()
     .then(docs => {
       let results = []   
       docs.map(doc => results.push(doc.data()))
       response.status(200).send(results)
     })
     .catch(e => resoponse.status(400).send(e))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, 
I've made edits to the code , unfortunately it is still not working, in Node.js environment nor in the cloud... 
I keep on getting a status 500 error code ...

Comment: This was most certainly an error in your existing code. There might have been more.

Comment: I got the cloud function to work ... the source of the error was in the .map function ... once i changed .map to forEach the function runs and data is returned

Comment: Good to hear. I was actually wondering if Firestore's snapshot implements map, since Firebase Realtime Database's snapshot does not. I guess you've found the answer for that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So after some trouble shooting I found the source of the problem . For some reason if you use .map on the return object the server will respond with a 500 status... 
change the .map to forEach and the function works

this will work ...

```
  admin.firestore().collection('news_stories')
    .get()
    .then(docs => {
        let data = []
        docs.forEach(doc => data.push(doc.data()))
       response.status(200).send(data)
  })
```

yet this wont ...

```
    admin.firestore().collection('news_stories')
      .get()
       .then(docs => {
         let data = []
         docs.map(doc => data.push(doc.data()))
         response.status(200).send(data)
     })
```